# Is there any reason to call new on POD structs in preallocated memory?

Tags: c++

I need to put an array of POD structs in a memory mapped file. Initially I looked for a way to call with a predefined address (which turns out to be new(address)) but since the struct doesn't even have a constructor is there any reason to do it at all? Can I just assign the view address to a pointer of the struct's type and use it as an array anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I just assign the view address to a pointer of the struct's type and use it as an array anyway?

Your question lacks specific detail. But I'd say yes you can. Placement new (the `new(address)` you speak of) would be ideal but you're right in that it's probably not necessary; the memory already belongs to you and there's no construction to perform.

Comment: Assuming that there exists some code that uses the data in these structures, I'd be inclined to put that within a class and rewrite the POD structs as classes.  If that's done, it would tilt the scales in favor of using placement `new`.

Comment: @Edward: I can get behind that.

Comment: The reason I want to avoid that is because I would be moving the view within the mmf, constructing new views and other various manipulation that I have no idea how to explain to c++ when it supposedly tracks memory allocated with new.